Conflicting requests - installing postgresql
I am trying to install Postgresql on my Amazon Linux machine on AWS, and I am getting the error of the conflicting request. and I got an option to add --skip-broken. whenever I add this flag it doesn't complete the installation.
I tried reinstalling, I also changed the Postgresql version.

Did you update packages before installing?
In other words, did you run:
$ sudo dnf update

Before:
$ sudo dnf install postgresql15.x86_64 postgresql15-server

(Installing postgresql 15 in this example; of course you may have installed another version).
?
If not, try that first.
Please provide the commands you ran in your question and screenshots of error messages if possible.

Yes, I did update package before installing. but it wasn't postgresql15. it was 13.

sudo dnf update -y
